# R/exams, numerical to single choice conversion

Tags: r-exams

I created a dynamic single choice question using `num_to_schoice()` function. I want to display 4 answers, 3 of which are typical errors.

An example:

```
sol<-300
wrong1 <-200
wrong2 <-100
wrong3<-400 
sc <- num_to_schoice(sol, wrong = c(wrong1,wrong2,wrong3), digits = 0)
```

Above creates 5 answers. How can I force it to display 4 answers? More specifically, is there a way to prevent R/exams from calculating additional wrong answers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need any ranodmly-generated wrong answers, then don't use `num_to_schoice()`. It's main purpose is generating some wrong answers in a certain `range` and with a certain `delta`.

If you already have all wrong solutions you need you can simply insert the answer list using a code chunk with:

```
answerlist("$", c(sol, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3), "$", sep = "", markup = ...)
```

where `...` would either be `"markdown"` or `"latex"` depending on the format of your exercise. (You may also want to omit the math markup with `$`. But `num_to_schoice()` includes it.)

In the metainformation you just need to set `exsolution` to `1000` and `exshuffle` to `TRUE` so that the answer list is shuffled randomly for each exercise.

Comment: Great! Thank you.